# non-linear ui slider value/placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

I want my ui slider to be at the second point of its array but have the textbox display the array value (20) when the page loads instead of its position (1).

placeholder & value html elements don't seem to work.

I have a fiddle for convenience: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fwfr0mnn/1/)

**The HTML**

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<input type="text" id="slider-val" value="20" />
```

**The JQuery**

```
$(function() {
    var valMap = [10, 20, 40, 80];
    $("#slider").slider({
        range: "max",
        max: valMap.length - 1,
        value: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            if (valMap[ui.value] > 0) {
                $("#slider-val").val(valMap[ui.value]);
            } else {
                $("#slider-val").val("1/" + (valMap[ui.value - 2]) * -1);
            }
            $(valMap[ui.value]).val($('#slider-val').val());
        }
    });
    $("#slider-val").val($("#slider").slider("value"));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the line:

```
$("#slider-val").val($("#slider").slider("value"));
```

with:

```
$("#slider-val").val(valMap[$("#slider").slider("value")]);
```

As you want to use the sliders value as an index in the `valMap` array.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fwfr0mnn/2/)